# React Native Facebook Login Android - Embedded Browser is disabled

Tags: android, react-native, facebook-android-sdk

I'm developing a facebook login feature for react native using [react-native-fbsdk-next](https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next). However when testing on android I get this error when trying to login with facebook: "For your account security, logging into Facebook from an embedded browser is disabled."

From looking at node modules it does seem like it's using facebookSdkVersion v12.+. Another thing to note is that I'm testing on an android emulator, could that affect things?

And is there any workaround for this issue or is it just something the client has to deal with?

Answer (score 0):

The library react-native-fbsdk has moved to react-native-fbsdk-next, they error you are facing may be due to the gradle cache issue, please use gradle clean and in the app/build.gradle add this code

```
ext{
...
facebookSdkVersion = "13.1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the url by **Linking** react-native package

Linking.openURL(url);